# Centering an "i" element in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, center

Can anyone think of a better way to center this "i" element into this div, without using pixel specific margins as I have done here.
It will be necessary, as the div the "i" element is in grows when hovering over it.

here is my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
  <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" id="bars"></i>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-collapse {
top: 30px;
right: 30px;
position: fixed;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: white;
z-index:200;
transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s;

}

.nav-collapse i{
position: absolute;
color: #FFB361;
}

#bars {
margin-left: 11px;
margin-top: 9px;
}


.nav-collapse:hover {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have italic text without any text?

Comment: The "i" tag in this case is used to implement "font awesome" icons.
take a look:
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Comment: Eugh. That's a revolting abuse of markup.

Comment: haha, It's not the worst.....And if the code works..... no problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform: scale(1.4)` instead of changing the `width` and `height`.

```css
.nav-collapse {
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 200;
  transition:  transform 0.2s;
}
.nav-collapse i {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFB361;
}
#bars {
  margin-left: 11px;
  margin-top: 9px;
}
.nav-collapse:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="nav-collapse">
  <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" id="bars"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

See output Below

- Add text-align: center and line-height:50px to div
- remove absolute position from i
- remove #bars style
- Add line-height:60px to hover state as height changes there

```css
.nav-collapse {
top: 30px;
right: 30px;
position: fixed;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
  line-height:50px;
background-color: white;
z-index:200;
transition: line-height 2s, width 0.2s, height 0.2s;
  text-align:center;
  background:red;

}

.nav-collapse i{

color: #FFB361;
}




.nav-collapse:hover {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
   line-height:60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-collapse">
  <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" id="bars">aa</i>
</div>
```

Comment: great solution! combining what both you and chipChocolate.py said has given me exactly what I wanted